# Provide a default value to a protocol property

Tags: swift

Consider this protocol and conforming objects

```swift
protocol Vehicle {
    var passengerCapacity: Int { get set }
}

class Cessna: Vehicle {
    var passengerCapacity = 4
}

struct Car: Vehicle {
    var passengerCapacity = 4
}
```

I want to add a property to it, `hasWheels`, which is able to be overwritten by the conforming objects, but also has a default value.

## Things I've tried

```swift
protocol Vehicle {
    var passengerCapacity: Int { get set }
    var hasWheels: Bool { get set } = true // Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
}
protocol Vehicle {
    var passengerCapacity: Int { get set }
    var hasWheels: Bool = true // Initial value is not allowed here
}


// This actually compiles, but you can't overwrite the value, it'll always return true

protocol Vehicle {
    var passengerCapacity: Int { get set }
    var hasWheels: Bool { get set }
}
extension Vehicle {
    var hasWheels: Bool {
        get {
            return true
        }
        set {
            // I think I need something here?
        }
    }    
}
```

Is this possible, or do I have no choice to but to add the property to every conforming struct and class?

Comment: You can overwrite the value of `hasWheels` in `Car` and `Cessna`. For example, `var hasWheels: Bool = false` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In practice a vehicle is not convertible with regard to the wheels, even James Bond's amphibious Lotus Esprit does have wheels, so a read-only property does the job.

Then the protocol extension works fine

```
protocol Vehicle {
    var passengerCapacity: Int { get set }
    var hasWheels: Bool { get }
}

extension Vehicle {
    var hasWheels: Bool { true }
}
```

And in a vehicle without wheels override the value

```
struct Cruiser: Vehicle {
    var passengerCapacity = 1000
    var hasWheels = false
}
```

Now a car has wheels

```
let car = Car()
print(car.hasWheels) // true
```

while a cruiser has not

```
let cruiser = Cruiser()
print(cruiser.hasWheels) // false
```

Comment: You’re missing the point, or I didn’t explain myself clearly enough. These aren’t really the protocols in my app, just examples. I don’t want to need to override the property in every conforming class, in practice I have over 20 in my app that I want to add a property too

Comment: You need to override the property only if the (default) value is supposed to be `false`. And as you are talking about ***classes***, in a class you have to provide an `init` method which can assign default values.

Comment: I am talking about structs and classes. What I’m trying to achieve is a property with a default value, that classes can optionally override. I don’t want to have to provide an implementation in every class or struct which conforms to this protocol. Really though what I want is to be able to say myStruct.hasWheels = false, without myStruct having to explicitly define hasWheels since it already conforms to the protocol. I recognise this may not be possible but wanted to post this question to find out.

Comment: Likely I’m indeed missing the point but this is exactly what the protocol extension does. Even if you don’t implement `hasWheels` in an object conforming to the protocol, the property is available with a default value of `true`.

Comment: @Will The problem with your proposal is that the property in the protocol extension doesn't work. It doesn't store a value given to it. It only returns a hardcode value. So any class or struct that conforms to the protocol but doesn't declare its own property will not have a working property.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a protocol with a property that has both a getter and a setter, you cannot provide a default value directly within the protocol. However, you can achieve similar behavior using protocol extension.

```
// protocol declaration 
protocol Vehicle {
    var passengerCapacity: Int { get set }
    var hasWheels: Bool { get set }
}

// protocol extension
extension Vehicle {
    var hasWheels: Bool {
        get {
            return true
        }
    }    
}
```

**You can overwrite the value like this**

```
class Car: Vehicle {
    var passengerCapacity: Int = 4
    var hasWheels: Bool = false
}

let carObj = Car()
print(carObj.hasWheels) // prints false for hasWheels
```

> when you extend the `protocol`, your are providing default
> value inside the `set { }`. In your case it give's the default value
> `false` for `hasWheels`

Comment: There's no protocol extension in the code you posted. Can you please clarify your answer.

Comment: I'm trying to show how the override is possible, as he said we can't override the property of a protocol.  I've updated my answer.